# Filter children in nested object

Tags: javascript

I have an object which I'm trying to filter out elements with a `path` and map, but I can't get past the first level into the nested children.

My object (with UI components removed):

```
  const items = [
    {
      path: "/login"
    },
    {
      path: "/help"
    },
    {
      name: "Guidelines",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Section 1",
          children: [
            {
              name: "Chapter 1",
              path: "/section-1/chapter-1"
            },
            {
              name: "Chapter 2",
              path: "/section-1/chapter-2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Section 2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "Chapter 3",
              path: "/section-2/chapter-3"
            },
            {
              name: "Chapter 4",
              path: "/section-2/chapter-4"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

This filters the elements with a path, but only to the first level:

```
const filteredRoutes = items.filter((route) => route.path);
```

Result:

```
[
 {"path":"/login"},
 {"path":"/help"}
]
```

My goal is to have a list of routes with 6 items in this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-napier-k3pwl?file=/src/App.js)

```
[
  { "path": "/login" },
  { "path": "/help" },
  { "path": "/section-1/chapter-1" },
  { "path": "/section-1/chapter-2" },
  { "path": "/section-2/chapter-3" },
  { "path": "/section-2/chapter-4" },
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getPath = (x) => (x.path ? { path: x.path } : x.children?.map(getPath));
const filteredRoutes = items && items.map(getPath).flat(Infinity);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm new in stackoverflow, and i don't know which point should add explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I'm marking this as the answer because it was the simplest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```js
  const findRoutesWithPaths = (routes) => {
    if (!routes) {
      return [];
    }

    const filteredRoutes = [];

    // Loop over all the routes
    routes.forEach((item) => {

      // Add `path` from self
      if (item.path) {
        filteredRoutes.push(item);
      }

      // Add `path`s from children
      if (item.children) {
        filteredRoutes.push(...findRoutesWithPaths(item.children));
      }
    });

    return filteredRoutes;
  };

  const filteredRoutes = findRoutesWithPaths(items);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-stonebraker-i4jb7?file=/src/App.js:785-1225)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I marked another response as the answer because it was simpler to implement in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
  const filteredRoutes = [];
    const arr = items.map((item) => {
    if (item.path) {
        filteredRoutes.push({"path" : item.path});
    } else {
        item.children.map((child) => {
        if (child.children) {
            child.children.map((_child) => {
            filteredRoutes.push({"path" : _child.path});
          })
        }
      })
    }
  });
  
  console.log(filteredRoutes);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I marked another response as the answer because it was simpler to implement in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Although you wanted to use the filter method, I found a way to iterate your array of objects recursively in case you have an unknown depth, your `pathArray` should have a length of 6 given the example data, but it will work of you have more children in your data as well.

```
var pathArray = [];
//Loop through all the objects in your items array
for (var k = 0; k < items.length; k++) {
    //For each object let's gather all the paths in the object
    var route = items[k];
    function getPath(obj) {
        //If the object has a "children" attribute then we should look inside
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
                getPath(obj.children[i]);
            }
        }
        // If not then this is the base level, which means there is a path attribute we need to grab
        else {
            pathArray.push(obj.path); //Add the path to our array
        }
    }
    getPath(route);
}
```

Let me know if you need any more clarification

Comment: Thanks for your response. I marked an answer below because it was simpler to implement for my use case.